# How to remove a value from dataframe based on the length of the column values using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In the following exp:

```
    class      Project 
  0  23454         Math
  1  23455         Physics
  2  456         Music
  3  45         Danse
  4  23455        Acting
```

How can i remove values in which the column values for class has less than 5 elements using the length function? So i will get the following dataframe:

```
    class      Project 
  0  23454     Math
  1  23455    Physics
  2           Music
  3           Danse
  4  23455    Acting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `mask()` and `astype()` for converting 'class' column to string and then check the length of string by `str.len()` if it is less then 5 or not so based on that mask change value:

```
df['class']=df['class'].mask(df['class'].astype(str).str.len().lt(5),'')
```

OR

via `loc` accessor

```
df.loc[df['class'].astype(str).str.len().lt(5),'class']=''
```

**Note:** similarly you can also use `np.where()` or `df.where()`

output:

```
    class   Project
0   23454   Math
1   23455   Physics
2           Music
3           Danse
4   23455   Acting
```